Perforce file conflict and missing interchange for re-added file
Perforce seems to get confused with regards to interchanges and merges when a file has been deleted and re-added only on the parent branch.
The below log demonstrates it pretty concisely:
PS C:\....\temporary_development_ws> p4 changes -r
Change 1 on 2024/12/18 by none@temporary_ws 'Stream //testing/mainline saved'
Change 2 on 2024/12/18 by none@temporary_ws 'Adding placeholder.txt'
Change 3 on 2024/12/18 by none@temporary_development_ws 'Stream //testing/development sa'
Change 4 on 2024/12/18 by none@temporary_development_ws 'Populate -S //testing/developme'
Change 5 on 2024/12/18 by none@temporary_ws 'Deleting placeholder.txt'
Change 6 on 2024/12/18 by none@temporary_ws 'Adding placeholder.txt again'

PS C:\....\temporary_development_ws> p4 interchanges //testing/mainline/... //testing/development/...
Change 6 on 2024/12/18 by none@temporary_ws 'Adding placeholder.txt again'

PS C:\....\temporary_development_ws> p4 integrate //testing/mainline/...@6 //testing/development/...
//testing/development/placeholder.txt#1 - integrate from //testing/mainline/placeholder.txt#3

PS C:\....\temporary_development_ws> p4 resolve -am
C:\....\temporary_development_ws\placeholder.txt - merging //testing/mainline/placeholder.txt#3
Diff chunks: 0 yours + 0 theirs + 0 both + 1 conflicting
//temporary_development_ws/placeholder.txt - resolve skipped.

i.e. if you create a new stream from another, even if you never make any changes on that new stream, a merge can produce a conflict, and the p4 interchanges list will ignore the delete changelist.
Are there any simple solutions to this? I'm writing an automated merge tool for p4 and would like to not have a developer needed to manually resolve the conflict or manually merge change 5.

Seems like a special case -- your tool could potentially have some extra logic that kicks in for a baseless merge and see if it wants to do an automatic resolve -at in specific scenarios.  The tricky thing here is that the situation is suddenly radically different when there have been changes on the target (either in the depot or the workspace), so you'll need to think carefully about how you want to handle that.  p4's built-in bias is to be very conservative when weird stuff like this happens and set up a baseless merge any time the source and target are logically different files.

Yeah. I can think of a few ways to attempt to safely resolve the conflict by looking at the history, but I'm trying to avoid that and perhaps there's a way to have p4 understand and not "self conflict" like this. It knows change 5 happened, surely there's a way for it to remember it without me having to "find" it in the file history, or to have to write my own conflict resolution algorithm.

There's not one currently built in, so you'd have to request it from Perforce.  (Writing your own conflict resolution algorithm isn't THAT hard IMO, but I understand it's not for everyone.  ;) )
